# mpfr(0.5) invalid floating point operation

Tags: python, precision, arbitrary-precision, mpfr

I hope I am not pointing out something obvious, or that the fix to this is not obvious.

I am using gmpy2 2.0.3 on a 64 bit windows 7 machine, coding with PyScripter. The following code gives an "Invalid floating point operation" error,

```
from gmpy2 import mpfr

mpfr(0.5)
```

Does this happen to anyone else? I understand that 0.5 = 0*1 + 1/2^(1), if that should inspire anything. Similarly, this also breaks,

```
from gmpy2 import mpfr

mpfr(0.25)
```

since 0.25 = 0*1 + 0*(1/2^1) + 1*(1/2^2).

Edit: I am new to the package, maybe some ideas on how to use if properly. Please pardon this if this question is no in the appropriate forum.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the maintainer of gmpy2 and those examples should work. I'm guessing there is an incompatibility between the CPU instruction set I chose when I compiled gmpy2 and your computer.

Can you open an issue report at https://code.google.com/p/gmpy/issues/list ?

Please include detailed system information.

Once we find the cause of the issue, I'll update this answer.

**Update**

I think I identified the cause and a new version is available at [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2/2.0.4b1). I cannot reproduce the issue so I can't be sure it has been fixed.